# TLS v1.0, Шифрование сообщение EncryptedHandshakeMessage (AES-256)

Tags: c#, криптография, tls, aes

Я пытаюсь зашифровать сообщение, при помощи AES (как клиент), но дело в том, что не совпадает последние 12 байтов:

СЕРВЕР - `3e106a0a312bdcc83d47f1768a53180ad8486bb188eb27aec1f1eede6d8a21a7`       `00d4a04e2882965a2b639b78c97bee40`
КЛИЕНТ - `3e106a0a312bdcc83d47f1768a53180ad8486bb188eb27aec1f1eede6d8a21a7` `f168b4bb4440b61b7b06e489457e6edc`

Место несовпадения на новой строке. Алгоритм AES-256

```
byte[] Server_EncryptedHandshakeMessage = AesTool.Encrypt(Completed, client_write_key, client_write_iv, PaddingMode.PKCS7);
```

Обратите внимание - `PaddingMode.PKCS7`

Функция - `Encrypt`:

```
internal static byte[] Encrypt(byte[] message, byte[] key, byte[] iv, PaddingMode PadMode )
{
    AesCryptoServiceProvider Aes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider();
    Aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
    Aes.KeySize = 128;
    Aes.Padding = PadMode;
    Aes.Key = key;
    Aes.IV = iv;
    ICryptoTransform encryptor = Aes.CreateEncryptor(key, iv);

    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
            using(BinaryWriter c = new BinaryWriter(csDecrypt))
            {
                c.Write(message);
            }

        }
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: Непонятно что с чем не совпадает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Очень похоже на несовместимость `PaddingMode` клиента и сервера. Для тестирования используйте и там и там `PaddingMode.Zeros`, который заполнит остаток нулями. Подробнее можете почитать тут: [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.security.cryptography.paddingmode(v=vs.110).aspx)

.p.s примеры с байтами лучше всего приводить в hex виде (например 0x01, 0x02 или 01 02).